# MATLAB - Count Number of Entries in Each Year

Tags: matlab, for-loop, count, while-loop, sum

I have a .mat file that contains data from the years 2006-2100. Each year, there is a different number of lines. I need to count how many lines are 2006, how many are 2007, etc.

The set up, by column, is: Year, Month, Day, Lat, Long
I just want to count the number of rows containing the same Year entry and get an array back with an array containing that info.

I'm thinking a for or while loop should work, but I don't know how to right it.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume your data are in a numeric matrix, you can just do:

```
num_lines2006 = sum(data(:,1)==2006);
data2006 = data(data(:,1)==2006),:);
```

---

If you want to add a column with number of rows for corresponding year, here is a solution with a loop:

```
for k=size(data,1):-1:1
    num_year(k,1) = sum(data(:,1)==data(k,1));
end
data = [data num_year];
```

---

Here is a solution without loop:

```
[unq_year,~,idx] = unique(data(:,1),'stable');
num_year = grpstats(data(:,1),unq_year,@numel);
data = [data num_year(idx)];
```

Comment: `grpstats` requires the statistics toolbox though.

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to count the number of rows you could just write something simple like:

```
years = unique(data(:, 1));
counts = arrayfun(@(year) nnz(data(:, 1) == year), years);
```

`years` contains the unique years, and `numRows` the number of times they are found.

You could also use a one-liner inspired by Jonas' answer:

```
[counts, years] = hist(data(:,1), unique(data(:,1))');
```

Answer (score 1):

To count numeric entries, you may want to use `histc`

```
years = unique(data(:,1);
counts = histc(data(:,1),years);
```